NodeJS это интерпретатор или компилятор?
Если учитывать, что он работает на движке V8, который выполняет компиляцию JavaScript в машинный код, то это компилятор.
Но данные в интернете (статьи на хабре/вопрос-ответы на хабре/другие сайты) говорят иначе: либо строго интепретатор, либо компилятор и интепретатор одновременно (разве такое может быть?).
После вышесказанного я не понимаю, можно ли с полной уверенностью назвать NodeJS компилятором?

Я бы не называл его компилятором. Создайте функцию с ошибкой(Даже синтаксической - просто текст вколотите произвольный). До тех пор, пока вы не обратитесь к этой функции, никаких ошибок выдано не будет - это говорит о том, что компиляция произошла в момнет обращения к функции.

node.js — ни то и не другое, но, в вашей постановке вопроса, скорее интерпретатор сценариев. Куда логичнее относиться к нему как к программной среде/платформе* работающей поверх операционной системы. Как по мне, то педивикия достаточно чётко формулирует определение. Попробуйте спросить себя что такое bash в Linux, а потом примерьтесь к php,  perl.. (суть в целом).

@SwaD, про синтаксическую ошибку неправда.

@Qwertiy Ну если брать прям совсем битый синтаксис, типа не закрытой скобки, то да. Возможно не так выразился...

Осмелюсь сказать что компилятора в Node.js больше чем, например, в TurboPascal.

С большого расстояния среды выполнения Java и JavaScript(Node.js/V8) подобны друг другу. Оба содержат и интерпретатор и компилятор. Кто-то сомневается что Java компилируемый язык? Другое дело, что не все языковые конструкции JavaScript могут быть откомпилированы прямо в машинный код. Но, если вы пишите аккуратно, без eval и прочих рефлексий, программа на JavaScript может быть целиком переведена в машинный код.

@SwaD, не бывает совсем битый и не совсем битый. console.log(1); function f() { 'use strict'; 00 } - вот, все скобки на месте.

Давайте разберём по пунктам:

Node.js – это рантайм, среда выполнения для программ на языке JavaScript, который содержит в себе движок V8.
V8 – это интерпретатор языка JavaScript с технологией JIT, Just-in-Time компиляции и VM, виртуальная машина, на которой полученный байт-код выполняется. Однако это в первую очередь интерпретатор, компиляция в машинный код происходит на лету, не формируется самодостаточного бинарного/байтового файла, который можно отдельно запускать вне V8 и рантайма, куда он встраивается, будь то Node.js или браузер.
Можно сравнить с языком Java, программы на котором схоже обрабатывается и переводится в байт-код, однако этот процесс называется именно компиляцией, т.к полученный файл хотя запускается только лишь на JVM, виртуальной машине Джавы, однако более не требует исходного кода для работы. В принципе, аналогично можно было бы сделать и для JS, но он для этого не предназначен.
Более того, JiT компиляция работает хитрым способом, предназначенным для языков со слабой и динамической типизацией – в процессе работы программы, анализируются используемые типы аргументов функций, и при должной статистике, части кода перекомпилируются под конкретные типы параметров, для повышения производительности (в V8 эти подходы называются Ignition и TurboFan). Согласитесь, это явно не классическая компиляция, где мы единожды получаем выходную программу и статически её выполняем в неизменном виде :)
Ещё обращу внимание, может кто не в курсе, сами языки не бывают компилируемыми или интерпретируемыми, ведь языки программирования это абстрактные наборы правил, и в теории любому языку можно разработать и интерпретатор, и компилятор, правда с разными усилиями, в зависимости от количества абстракций в спецификации языка.


Подробнее про режимы JiT компиляции
Понятнее будет объяснить через хронологию выполнения кода:
Изначально, при выполнении какого-то JS кода, сперва он транслируется в не-оптимизированный, но универсальный байт-код. Этот байт-код выполняется на движке V8, но работает медленно, т.к не зная о входящих типах аргументов, они все трактуются как что угодно, требуя повсеместного использования динамической диспатчеризацией, т.е резолвинге методов и операторов через словари прототипов объектов, что обеспечивает полиморфизм в условиях слабой динамической типизации.
Затем, со сбором статистики, выполняются эвристические правила, которые оценивают, что вот эти функции работают, например, только с числами, следовательно здесь можно сразу вызывать арифметические операции, и в новом оптимизированном байт-коде прописывается указатель на соответствующую пользовательскую или внутреннюю функцию. Соответственно, так мы сильно сокращаем работу с обращением в словари в поисках значений строковых имён атрибутов, что и приводит к заметному приросту производительности.
Полученная новая версия байт-кода можно сказать написана на том же языке, что и прежняя, однако является более эффективной её реализацией (примерно как сортировка пузырьком и быстрая/слиянием). Новая версия байт-кода функции выполняется в том же самом процессе V8, просто заменяет прежнюю версию, и последующие обращения к функции будут эффективнее.
Кстати, стандартный интерпретатор Питона, CPython, работает аналогично первой части – он тоже транслирует исходный текст программы в байт-код. Также существует альтернативная имплементация, которая содержит JIT компиляцию: PyPy

"Классическая компиляция" как вы её описали не самая классическая. CommonLisp содержит куда более старый компилятор, но он и с динамической типизацией и с компиляцией кода во время работы программы, если это необходимо. И тем не менее он компилируется во вполне статичный исполнимый файл из машинных инструкций. Просто этот файл заодно и сам компилятор может содержать.

@AivanF. Спасибо за ответ. Т.е. получается что проводится интерпретация первично в байт-код, а после компиляция на лету? Компиляция на лету в таком случае проводится определённых фрагментов байт-кода? Или полностью всего байт-кода?

@Yulia возможно вы не так поняли: компиляции иной чем в байт-код для ВМ здесь нет, но этот байт-код может быть разной степени оптимизации. Увлёкся пояснением и в комментарий уже не поместилось, так что дополнил ответ. И всегда пожалуйста

@AivanF. Так-с, в голове вроде уложилось. Но есть потребность еще раз спросить: получается у нас есть первичная интерпретация в байт-код. Итоговый байт-код неоптимизированный. Потом Turbofan, например, проводит JIT-компиляцию на лету и мы имеем машинный код. Машинный код и байт-код, которые существуют одновременно? И байт-код выполняется виртуальной машиной (если его еще не оптимизировали), а компилированный машинный код непосредственно процессором?

@Yulia Повторюсь, кроме байт-кода в этом процессе на выходе ничего не бывает :) Всегда получается байткод, но он может быть с динамической или статической диспетчиризацией, в чём и заключается вся суть производительности.
Компилировать в машинной код излишне запарно: это потребовало бы поддержки 2х разных подходов к реализации, а также встраивания и сопровождения компилятора со спецификой кучи разных процессоров, при этом прирост производительности будет малым в сравнении с текущим подходом, где встроенные функции и так написаны на C++ и выполняются без интерпретации.

@AivanF. , И все же, TurboFan делает только оптимизированный байт-код или производит трансляцию байт-кода в  native code,  как утверждает в своем ответе StanislavVolodarskiy ?

Языки программирования уже давно однозначно не делятся на интерпретируемые и компилируемые. Так и JS нельзя отнести ни к одной из этих категорий.
Поскольку он принимает код на человекочитаемом языке и не производит файл с результатом компиляции, я считаю, что он является интерпретатором.
Если не ошибаюсь, для языков, исполняющих промежуточный байткод (джава и C#) этот исполнитель вообще принято называть виртуальной машиной. Но поскольку в js на вход попадает исходный код, а не промежуточный, я за интерпретатор.

А в Питоне .py компилируется в .pyc, .pyo, который может быть исполнен в отсутствие исходного файла. Но это не делает Питон компилируемым языком. Слишком много конструкций, которые на процессор прямо не отображаются.

Спасибо за ответ

@StanislavVolodarskiy Значит Питон неинтерпретируемый и некомпилируемый, а исполнитель виртуальная машина? Почему тогда везде он интерпретируемый?

@Handler, это значит что чёткое разделение между интерпретаторами и компиляторами стёрлось в конце прошлого века. Сейчас абсолютно все популярные языки компилируются в промежуточное представление (и это именно компиляция, но без кодогенерации на целевую платформу). Что делать с промежуточным представлением решается позже: можно исполнять непосредственно, можно генерировать машинный код, можно сочетать оба подхода). CPython компилирует и интерпретирует. PyPy компилирует и порождает машинный код (где может). Numba тоже, причём она встраивается в CPython.

@StanislavVolodarskiy насколько я помню из универа, процесс перевода в байт-код и т.п представления, исполняемые только на виртуальных машинах, в рантаймах, официально называется трансляцией, а компиляцией строго говоря именуется только трансляция в машинный код, в бинарь выполняемый процессором напрямую.

@AivanF., "Компили́ровать — проводить сборку машинной программы, включая: трансляцию с предметно-ориентированного языка на машинно-ориентированный язык..." Компилятор. Без микроскопа я компилятор от транслятора не отличаю.

@AivanF., а как в вашем универе называли процесс трансляции машинных инструкций одной архитектуры (например, x86) в другую (например, aarch64)?

@avp, я бы предположил, что конвертером?

@Qwertiy, у нас это тоже называют трансляцией

Как вы правильно заметили Node.js использует V8:

Node.js runs on the V8 JavaScript engine...

А V8 основан на интерпретаторе и компиляторе:

In 2017, V8 shipped a brand-new compiler pipeline, consisting of Ignition (the interpreter) and TurboFan (the optimizing compiler).

Причём TurboFan настоящий оптимизирующий компилятор с кодогенерацией, распределением регистров и прочими атрибутами "нормальных" компиляторов, вроде C и C++.

Спасибо за ответ.
